# Admin Login Checks

Tags: wp-admin, admin, login

Where does WordPress perform the check as to whether or not a user is logged in when aaccessing admin? i.e. When I access /wp-admin/edit.php, if I am not logged in I am redirected to the login page - where (which file) is that process taking place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It begins on [this line](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d7b49bbc3ea6c875ee05ebf04188c8f3babc52aa/wp-admin/admin.php#L84) in the `admin.php` file, which is a part of all admin-related backend pages in WordPress. That line calls upon the [`auth_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/auth_redirect/) function, which handles the redirection.